# How can I overcome this 'too broad' verdict, and/or find a better forum for my question?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

I recently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542851/whats-the-easiest-way-for-an-absolute-beginner-to-use-a-big-list-of-spellchec) and after a little discussion in the comments, it was put on hold as too broad. I've tried adding some edits explaining my situation, but to no avail. The problem I'm trying to solve is such a common and specific problem that I would guess that there is a well-known standard way of solving it, in which case a correct answer would simply point me to the standard solution. But maybe I'm wrong about that. If the problem is that the question is for beginners, then is there a forum for such questions?

Thanks.

Comment: The "specific" question seems to be 'how to write a program' which is pretty broad.

Comment: No, the specific question is how to use a custom spellcheck list to correct a piece of text. I would expect that this could be done using Microsoft Word or even some simple website designed specifically for that purpose, rather than by downloading programming software, learning a programming language, and writing a program de novo.

Comment: Forgot to mention this earlier but-  using your list to spell check will be really fragile.  Its about the worst way of spellchecking possible-  you have a list of common typos and will correct those, but it will miss anything not in the list and show no intelligence for other near misses, homophones, etc.  You're probably better off just using the default spellcheck in word anyway.

Comment: @GabeSechan No, I think you're wrong about that. The default spellcheck in Word gets things wrong a lot, e.g. replacing 'fcarce' with 'farce' instead of replacing it with 'scarce'. And the computerized spellcheck is not the only proofing this text will be undergoing. It's just a necessary first step, as a way of avoiding hours and days of tedious manual correction.

Comment: Check out my linkedin resume.  I was a lead at Swype, I've written autocorrect and spell check algorithms.  Your file is 1970s technology, its basically what you'd get if you asked a CS101 student to write a spell checker.  It wouldn't even be using difference hashing or frequency tables to score between multiple alternatives.  It may get 1 or 2 things right that word doesn't, but it will get 10 times as many wrong.  This is a field where I am an expert-  that list is not a good way to do spell checking.  For example, it would say zksksksksks is a good word, because it isn't in the list.

Comment: @GabeSechan Do you have experience with spellchecking plain text resulting from OCRing 18th century texts with a lot of long s's? Because the long s problem is the main one I'm trying to solve, and the main one that list was designed to solve. It's obvious that Word's default spellcheck is useless at solving that problem, so do you have a recommendation for a different way of solving it?

Comment: YOur list wouldn't actually even do spell checking completely-  because it doesn't have a dictionary, so it wouldn't be able to tell a word is real or not unless it had a common misspelling.  The list you have really isn't meant for spelling corrections-  its meant to be analyzed by computational linguists to come up with better algorithms.

Comment: @GabeSechan All I'm trying to do is replace all instances of 'fcarce' with 'scarce', and likewise for all other common OCR errors in the text. All other forms of proofing can be done manually.

Comment: For that one specific problem, I'd use search and replace.  The next problem you're going to run into though is that the kind of typos OCR makes and the type of typos humans make aren't normally the same, nor are typos in handwriting the same as typing.  So the list won't help much at all, unless the list was generated from past OCR attempts. What you're looking for is what computational linguists get research grants for.

Comment: @GabeSechan But manual search and replace will take hours if not days. I'd like to do it all at once. And yes, the list was indeed generated from past OCR attempts. See http://usesofscale.com/gritty-details/basic-ocr-correction/

Comment: Ok, that improves the value of the list at least slightly.  What might be valuable is running it as a first pass and then running a more advanced spell checker on it.  We're spamming the rest of the readers, why don't you follow up with me at gsechan@hotmail.com.  Since its not a horribly complicated project and it seems like its obviously an academic one I may be willing to throw something together for you over the weekend.

Comment: @GabeSechan OK, I've sent you an email.

Answer (score 11):

That question is *ridiculously* broad.

It wasn't closed because it was "beginner" level, it was closed *because you asked for the whole program*. Even worse, you effectively asked for it an *any language*. Its hard to get much broader.

I sympathize with you not understanding where to start, but you need to try some things, then come back with specific questions about your attempt. You may want to read [What Have You Tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) . It is a good article for people learning how to learn to program.

**Note:** There is no SE site that this question would be appropriate for.

Comment: I didn't ask for "the whole program". On the contrary, I'm not even sure a program is needed. I would expect that it could be done via Microsoft Word, and indeed the commenter who tried to help suggested a (seemingly unsuccessful) way of doing it with Word. Are you saying that the only way to use a custom spellcheck list is to get some programming software and learn a programming language? That seems like overkill.

Comment: @76987 If the solution is Word, or otherwise non-programmatic, then the question is off-topic here and should be on Super User (note, I would *strongly* reccommend rewording the question before posting there). If the solution *is* programmatic, then no answer besides the whole program could have been offered. So even though you may not have *explicitly* asked for it, you still basically asked for the whole thing.

Comment: OK, so I guess I'm going to ask it on Super User. Unfortunately, though, I have no idea how it should be reworded. Was it somehow unclear as presently worded?

Comment: @76987 Not unclear, but I would remove a lot of fluff. You already have this as plain text that you could paste into Word? If so, then simply ask how to run spell check rules from some source through Word. Context is important, but *too much* context makes the whole thing noise. Its a delicate balance to strike. Make sure to *not* make it about programming, since thats not what Super User is for.

Comment: I posted a question on Super User. Please let me know if it contains too much 'fluff' or too much context.

Comment: @76987 That looks reasonably well put to me. Hope you get a good answer! You may want to provide a sample of what one of your "rules" looks like (in the list) so people know if its possible.

Answer (score 4):

This is a website for programmers-  particularly for professionals and skilled amateurs, not for teaching the basics of programming.  Asking how to effectively search within that list in a given language in and of itself would be on topic but very very basic.  But our answer would be to teach someone how to write the program, and we would do so assuming someone already knew the basics.  If you don't, you're better off finding another website where they will either teach you how to code, or where you can hire someone to do so for you.

Comment: My response to BradleyDotNET addresses the focus on programming/coding. But it's worth noting that I'm not asking how to search within the list. That can be done even with the list pulled up in the browser. I'm asking how to use the list as a spellcheck on a piece of text.

Comment: Search has a specific meaning in programming.  Searching the list means walking the list to find a match-  its the algorithm you would use to do that.  SInce you have misspelled words in 1 column and corrections in another you would search the list to see if a word is anywhere in column one, and if so replace it with column 2.  The fact it wasn't immediately obvious to you what searching a list meant and why it applies is another sign that this isn't the website you should be posting this question at.

Comment: Well, that's why I asked if there was a better forum for the question.